# Railsで生SQLを使う際にパラメータを利用する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql

Railsで生sqlを利用して下記のようなsqlを書きました。

```
【Like table】
id
action_user_id
target_user_id

sql
@user = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select('select target_user_id, count(id)  from Likes where action_user_id is ##### group by target_user_id order by count(id)')
```

上記の###にパラメータを渡し、

```
@id = User.find(#).id
@user = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select('select target_user_id, count(id)  from Likes where action_user_id is @id group by target_user_id order by count(id)')
```

のようにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

アドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

(直接の回答ではありません) 目的が生SQLを書くことでは無く、そのSQLと等価なことをしたいというのであれば、ActiveRecordを普通に使うことで実現可能です。

```
@user = Like.where(:action_user_id => @id).group(:target_user_id).order("count(id)").select("target_user_id, count(id) AS count")
@user.map { |u| [u.target_user_id, u.count] }
#=> [[1, 4], [2, 4], [0, 5], [3, 10], [4, 12]] こんな感じで出ます
```

もちろん、`where("action_user_id = ?", @id)` としてプレースホルダを使うこともできます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！
selectをうまく使えばactiverecordでできるんですね！
勉強になりました

Answer (score 1):

現在のrails guide を読む限り #select_all が推奨されているように思えます。SQL処理の結果をActiveRecordで受け取るなら #find_by_sql が使えますがいかがでしょうか。
[find_by_sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql)
[select_all](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select-all)
あと、月並みな考え方ですが、サンプルコードにあるSQLの中に @id を埋め込むのは、文字列に直接インターポレーション(#{...})するスタイルが使えるので、コーディング上の理由等で差し支えがないのであれば、そのスタイルを使うので十分かと思います。

```
"select target_user_id, count(id)  from Likes where action_user_id = #{@id} group by target_user_id order by count(id)"
```

Comment: 文字列連結や変数展開でパラメータを埋め込むのであれば、この例では必ず`@id`が数値であることを検証する必要があります。検証漏れがあるとSQLインジェクション脆弱性が生じます。数値パラメータの場合、「この変数には数値が入っているはず」という思い込みが生じやすいため特に危険です。このように特別な注意が必要になりますので、可能な限り文字列連結や変数展開によるSQLの生成は避けるべき方法です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ご指摘の通りselect_allでできました！